# Python ctypes deepcopy structure

Tags: python, ctypes, deep-copy

I am not very used to python ctypes, so sorry if this is a naive question. I am trying to copy a struct, this is my code:

```py
from ctypes import *

class Group(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ChSize", c_uint32*9),
        ("DataChannel", POINTER(c_float)*9),
        ("TriggerTimeLag", c_uint32),
        ("StartIndexCell", c_uint16)]
    
    def deepcopy(self):
        copy = Group()
        for n_channel in range(9):
            data_buffer = c_float*self.ChSize[n_channel]
            memmove(
                addressof(data_buffer),
                self.DataChannel[n_channel], 
                self.ChSize[n_channel]*sizeof(c_float),
            )
            copy.ChSize[n_channel] = self.ChSize[n_channel]
            copy.DataChannel[n_channel] = addressof(data_buffer)
            copy.TriggerTimeLag = self.TriggerTimeLag
            copy.StartIndexCell = self.StartIndexCell
        return copy
```

However, when I try to use it, I get

```
TypeError: invalid type
```

What would be the correct way of creating a complete new copy of a `Group` object?

Comment: *ChSize* member contains *DataChannel* sizes? If yes, in bytes or in elements?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure, this comes from a black box library, but I can try the different cases until I get it to work.

Comment: If you don't know, how do you know how much data in that pointer you are allowed to access? The library must have come with some documentation (if the structure is part of public API). If it isn't the case, then maybe your whole approach from the other question is wrong, and you should only call *release\_memory* once you're done with the structure.

Comment: I would assume the 9 sizes represent the number of floats in the arrays pointed to by the 9 data channels, but instead of copying, I agree with @CristiFati that releasing the data once you are done with it in Python would be more straightforward.  You could do that explicitly with a `.release()` method, or implicitly with a `__del__()`.  I'll give you an answer on my first assumption, however.

Comment: This is a voltage digitizer, similar to an oscilloscope. There, I have the waveforms. I know each waveform has 1024 samples. This code is inside a `while system_is_running` loop digitizing all the time, and I need to save the waveforms into a file. Currently I convert on the fly each individual waveform to numpy arrays and it works, but I am looking to speed it up by not decoding each waveform individually on the fly, but trying to save the whole raw struct and decoding afterwards. But I cannot manage to copy the data from these events other than using numpy individually for each waveform.

Comment: Anyhow, if I have to iterate in this way it will be the same, but this would be a starting point to later approach it without splitting each channel.

Comment: manipulating data directly with ctypes is usually slower than numpy due to all the data copies.

Comment: You could use the `__repr__()` method in my answer to dump the data of a *real* `Group` returned by your library and see what the data looks like for `ChSize` and `DataChannel`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the nine sizes represent the length of each float array pointed to by each of the nine DataChannel pointers:

```py
import ctypes as ct

class Group(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('ChSize', ct.c_uint32 * 9),
                ('DataChannel', ct.POINTER(ct.c_float) * 9),
                ('TriggerTimeLag', ct.c_uint32),
                ('StartIndexCell', ct.c_uint16))

    def __repr__(self):
        s = f'Group(ChSize={self.ChSize[:]}, TriggerTimeLag={self.TriggerTimeLag}, StartIndexCell={self.StartIndexCell})\n'
        for i in range(9):
            s += f'  DataChannel[{i}] = {self.DataChannel[i][:self.ChSize[i]]}\n'
        return s

    def deepcopy(self):
        copy = Group.from_buffer_copy(self)  # make a shallow copy
        # Note: at this point the data channels point to the original group
        for i, (size, channel) in enumerate(zip(self.ChSize, self.DataChannel)):  # iterate channels
            data = (ct.c_float * size)(*channel[:size]) # make a copy of the data for a channel
            copy.DataChannel[i] = ct.cast(data, ct.POINTER(ct.c_float))  # store a pointer to that data in the copy
        return copy

# Validation

# Create, initialize and display a group
group = Group()
group.ChSize[:] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i, size in enumerate(group.ChSize):
    data = (ct.c_float * size)(*[1.5 * n for n in range(size)])
    group.DataChannel[i] = ct.cast(data, ct.POINTER(ct.c_float))
group.TriggerTimeLag = 123
group.StartIndexCell = 456
print(group)

copy = group.deepcopy()  # make a copy

# Zero out the channels of the original
group.ChSize[:] = [0] * 9
group.DataChannel[:] = [None] * 9

print(group)  # display zeroed-out group
print(copy)   # display copy
```

Output:

```
Group(ChSize=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], TriggerTimeLag=123, StartIndexCell=456)
  DataChannel[0] = [0.0]
  DataChannel[1] = [0.0, 1.5]
  DataChannel[2] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0]
  DataChannel[3] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5]
  DataChannel[4] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0]
  DataChannel[5] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5]
  DataChannel[6] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0]
  DataChannel[7] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0, 10.5]
  DataChannel[8] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0, 10.5, 12.0]

Group(ChSize=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], TriggerTimeLag=123, StartIndexCell=456)
  DataChannel[0] = []
  DataChannel[1] = []
  DataChannel[2] = []
  DataChannel[3] = []
  DataChannel[4] = []
  DataChannel[5] = []
  DataChannel[6] = []
  DataChannel[7] = []
  DataChannel[8] = []

Group(ChSize=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], TriggerTimeLag=123, StartIndexCell=456)
  DataChannel[0] = [0.0]
  DataChannel[1] = [0.0, 1.5]
  DataChannel[2] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0]
  DataChannel[3] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5]
  DataChannel[4] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0]
  DataChannel[5] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5]
  DataChannel[6] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0]
  DataChannel[7] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0, 10.5]
  DataChannel[8] = [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0, 10.5, 12.0]
```